# How to return a single promise after for loop where every element of an array inside loop do multi async calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I Have a array of objects which i need to clone with different values.

Those values i'll get from each promise finally after preparing main modified array of object i'll have to save this. So i many need this as one single promise.

I not sure how to do it.

Here is the example we need to clone oldUser data. Say old user has credit score = 100; but for new user default credit will be created randomly by system.

For each user in the array of users few details has to get updated using async call. 
This is the requirement

```
function getUserCreditScore(user){
  var url = '/someurl';
  return $http.get(url).then(function(res){
    user.creditScore = (res.data) ? res.data : 0;
  });
}

function getUserRecomandations(user){
   var url = '/someurl';
  return $http.get(url).then(function(res){
   user.recommendation = (res.data) ? res.data : 'basic recommendation';
  });
}  

function getUserHelpInfo(user){
   var url = '/someurl';
  return $http.get(url).then(function(res){
   user.helpInfo = (res.data) ? res.data : 'Help Info';
  });
}  


function clone(){
  var newUsers = angular.copy(oldUsers);

  for (var i=0; i<newUsers.length; i++){
    newUsers[i].id = undefined;
    getUserCreditScore(newUsers[i]);
    getUserRecommendation(newUsers[i]);
    getUserHelpInfo(newUsers[i]);
  }

  var promises = _.map(newUsers, user => user.save());
  $q.all(promises).then(function (data) {
   console.log(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to wait for the promise returned by `getCreditScore(newUsers[i]);` ... also, your `function getCreditScore(user){` never uses the user argument? so it's difficult to know what you are attempting to do

Comment: My bad the getCreditScore looks like below
     function getCreditScore(user){
       var url = '/someurl';
       return $http.get(url).then(function(res){
         user.creditScore = (res.data) ? res.data : 0;
        });
      }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to Promise.all on an array of Promises that are returned by `getScreditScore`

something like

```
function getCreditScore(){
    var url = '/someurl';
    return $http.get(url).then(res => (res && res.data) ? res.data : res);
}

function clone(){
    var newUsers = angular.copy(oldUsers);

    Promise.all(
        newUsers.map(newUser => {
            newUser.id = undefined;
            return getCreditScore()
            .then(result => newUser.creditScore = result);
        })
    ).then(results => // results will be an array of values returned by the get in getCreditScore(newUser)
        Promise.all(newUsers.map(user => user.save()))
    ).then(data =>
        console.log(data); // this will be the result of all the user.save
    );
}
```

Note: the `newUser.creditScore` is set in the .then in the `newUsers.map` callback - (minimal change to my original answer)

Alternatively, passing user to `getCreditScore`

```
function getCreditScore(user){
    var url = '/someurl';
    return $http.get(url)
    .then(res => (res && res.data) ? res.data : res)
    .then(score => user.creditScore = score);
}

function clone(){
    var newUsers = angular.copy(oldUsers);

    Promise.all(
        newUsers.map(newUser => {
            newUser.id = undefined;
            return getCreditScore(newUser);
        })
    ).then(results => // results will be an array of values returned by the get in getCreditScore(newUser)
        Promise.all(newUsers.map(user => user.save()))
    ).then(data =>
        console.log(data); // this will be the result of all the user.save
    );
}
```

> Personally, I'd write the code

```
function getCreditScore(){
    var url = '/someurl';
    return $http.get(url).then(res => (res && res.data) ? res.data : res);
}

function clone(){
    var newUsers = angular.copy(oldUsers);

    Promise.all(
        newUsers.map(newUser => {
            newUser.id = undefined;
            return getCreditScore()
            .then(result => newUser.creditScore = result)
            .then(() => newUser.save())
            .then(() => newUser);
        })
    ).then(data =>
        console.log(data); // this will be the newUsers Array
    );
}
```

This assumes, though, that you don't need to wait for all the $http.get before running the `user.save()` - in fact this may be a little (very little) more performant as the `newUser.save` and `$http.get` will run in tandem

Comment: Thanks so much Jaromanda X. But I can't return getCreditScore(newUser); as i need two more promise values to be updated to newUser object before final save. How do i do it?

Comment: `i need two more promise values to be updated to newUser object` - I can't see how that is mentioned in your question - I take it you can't use the techniques I've shown in the answer yourself in the code you haven't shown or even made the slightest mention of until now?

Comment: Sorry for my poor question make. I have not mentioned it in the summary but I have mentioned it in the question(title).

Comment: no, your title suggests your talking about the many promises of the array ... chain the promises, or use Promise.all to make multiple asynchronous tasks at once - I can't show more code than you've shown, because I don't know where or what these "many promises" are - you either show in your question or live with the fact that I can't read your mind

Comment: Oh!! ok  Jaromanda X. I have updated the actual question in summary. Hope it is clear

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know your meaning, you want your every element of your array do something that is async.

So you can use map and Promise.all. Here is my code:

```
const asyncFunction = (item, cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`done with ${item}`);
    cb();
  }, 1000);
}

let requests = [1, 2, 3].map((item) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) =>{
    asyncFunction(item, resolve);
  });
});

Promise.all(requests).then(() => console.log('done'));
```

Comment: Thanks yzfdjzwl. I'll give a try.